# Problemas para Subir carpeta a Git (M)

Tags: git, vscode

me encuentro con un problema al subir mi proyecto desde VsCode a Git. No me deja  subir la Carpeta imagenes. Ya utilicé git add . Si a alguno le paso similar y mr puede dar una mano, se lo agradecería.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y has probado `git add imagenes`? La carpeta no puede estar vacía.

Answer (score 2):

revisa si la carpeta no este en .gitignore si no esta, ejecuta este comando
git add -A . para colocar todos los archivos que quieras hacer commit y luego revisar si la carpeta ya se ve con el comando git status

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Como dijo arriba Vesper, verifica eso, de lo contrario, si sigue igual, utiliza directamente el CMD, yo tuve ese error y ahora solo subo la carpeta y actualizo todo desde el CMD, sin problemas. Saludos cordiales

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).